# How to implement this for loop more elegant with numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

this is some snippet of my code. Can someone the appropriate 
way to do this. Some fancy NumPy trick?

```
q_val = np.random.rand(5,3) 

action = np.ones((5,1),int)
to_set = np.ones((5,1),int)
for x in range(5):
     q_val[x][action[x]] -= to_set[x]
```

This is how I instantiate the values

```
q_val = np.random.rand(5,3) //lets say the middel of randome
q_val = array([[0.93373647, 0.        , 0.14962181],//get only zeroes
       [0.67909199, 0.        , 0.07462584],
       [0.05696713, 0.        , 0.03221326],
       [0.78209394, 0.        , 0.58312439],
       [0.09217555, 0.        , 0.17876316]])                           
action = np.ones((5,1),int)
action = >>> action
array([[1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]])

to_set = np.ones((5,1),int)
to_set = array([[1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]])
```

This what I will change

```
for x in range(5):
     q_val[x][action[x]] -= to_set[x]
```

This what I will get

```
array([[ 0.93373647, -1.        ,  0.14962181],
       [ 0.67909199, -1.        ,  0.07462584],
       [ 0.05696713, -1.        ,  0.03221326],
       [ 0.78209394, -1.        ,  0.58312439],
       [ 0.09217555, -1.        ,  0.17876316]])
```

I am sure there is some fancy method to do this in one of line.
Can someone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it is unlikely to benefit future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use arrays for indexing into other arrays:

```
index = np.arange(len(action))
q_val[index, action] -= to_set[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

Easily, this could be rewritten as:

```
q_val[:,1] -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The one-line result was

```
q_val[:,action] -= to_set
```